# store the path of file in variable using angular 4

Tags: angular, api, file, typescript

i want to upload file by storing the path of this file in variable :

```
 <input type="file" fromControlName="file" />
```

it's a field of many field in form , i want to upload it

```
 storeSubjects(subject : Subjects){
        let url = 'http://api.azharcouncil.com/api/subjects/PostSubject?code='+subject.code+'&Type_ID='+subject.kindOfSub+'&Faculty_Id='+subject.name+
        '&Main_Tittle='+subject.mainTitle+'&Child_Tittle='+subject.subTitle+'&Description='+subject.description+'&Notes='+subject.notes+'&Subject_Path='+subject.file;
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
        return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(subject), options);
    }
```

i want to make &Subject_Path= (path of file)

Answer (score 0):

> upload file by storing the path of this file

The path to file is **not exposed through HTML**. It would be a potential security issue if the absolute path could be read. The only thing you can get is name; it's a part of the `File` you can get through events like `onchange` or `oninput`.

Comment: how can i use those events to make the backend know this file and store it ?